How to extract actual database error instead of the generic transaction aborted error in Postgresql Sequelize transaction
I am using transaction in my sequelize-typescript for creating a record which looks like this
return await this.sequelize.transaction(async (transaction) => {
        const borrower = await this.onBoardingServiceDao.createBorrower(
          body,
          transaction,
        );
        await this.onBoardingServiceDao.createUserBorrowerMapping(
          { userid: userId, borrowerid: borrower.id },
          transaction,
        );
        return borrower;
      });

The onboardingServiceDao > createBorrower looks like this
public async createBorrower(body, transaction: Transaction) {
    return await this.borrowerModel.create(body, { transaction });
  }

Now some of the columns in the Borrower table have a unique constraint set on them. When I get a POST request with the column value being already present, it is throwing me: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
However if I remove the usage of transaction and simply do a normal create, then it gives me proper error saying: original: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "borrowers_unique_cin" which is more understandable and can be shown on the frontend to the user as error message.
I still want to use transactions in my create, is there a way to extract what exactly went wrong in the db operation instead of a generic transaction aborted error message?
I tried wrapping the createBorrower dao service in try-catch but the error caught has the generic 25P02 error and not the actual "unique constraint violation error". Is there a way to intercept the original error before the transaction rollback and abortion happens.
Stack trace for the db transaction abortion error
{
  name: "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  parent: {
    length: 145,
    name: "error",
    severity: "ERROR",
    code: "25P02",
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: "postgres.c",
    line: "1498",
    routine: "exec_parse_message",
    sql: "INSERT INTO \"public\".\"borrowers\" (\"id\",\"company_name\",\"company_pan\",\"company_cin\",\"contact_email\",\"contact_phone1\",\"contact_phone2\",\"company_website\",\"company_linkedin\",\"registration_type\",\"status\",\"operating_sectors\",\"incorporation_year\") VALUES (gen_random_uuid(),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12) RETURNING \"id\",\"company_name\",\"company_pan\",\"company_cin\",\"contact_email\",\"contact_phone1\",\"contact_phone2\",\"company_website\",\"company_linkedin\",\"registration_type\",\"status\",\"operating_sectors\",\"incorporation_year\",\"onboarding_completed_at\",\"gdrive_folder_id\";",
    parameters: [
      "ABC Software Technologies",
      "ABC",
      "CFE",
      "test@email.com",
      "9999999999",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      1,
      3,
      [
        "ADVISORY_SERVICES",
      ],
      2009,
    ],
  },
  original: {
    length: 145,
    name: "error",
    severity: "ERROR",
    code: "25P02",
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: "postgres.c",
    line: "1498",
    routine: "exec_parse_message",
    sql: "INSERT INTO \"public\".\"borrowers\" (\"id\",\"company_name\",\"company_pan\",\"company_cin\",\"contact_email\",\"contact_phone1\",\"contact_phone2\",\"company_website\",\"company_linkedin\",\"registration_type\",\"status\",\"operating_sectors\",\"incorporation_year\") VALUES (gen_random_uuid(),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12) RETURNING \"id\",\"company_name\",\"company_pan\",\"company_cin\",\"contact_email\",\"contact_phone1\",\"contact_phone2\",\"company_website\",\"company_linkedin\",\"registration_type\",\"status\",\"operating_sectors\",\"incorporation_year\",\"onboarding_completed_at\",\"gdrive_folder_id\";",
    parameters: [
      "ABC Software Technologies",
      "ABC",
      "CFE",
      "test@email.com",
      "9999999999",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      1,
      3,
      [
        "ADVISORY_SERVICES",
      ],
      2009,
    ],
  },
  sql: "INSERT INTO \"public\".\"borrowers\" (\"id\",\"company_name\",\"company_pan\",\"company_cin\",\"contact_email\",\"contact_phone1\",\"contact_phone2\",\"company_website\",\"company_linkedin\",\"registration_type\",\"status\",\"operating_sectors\",\"incorporation_year\") VALUES (gen_random_uuid(),$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12) RETURNING \"id\",\"company_name\",\"company_pan\",\"company_cin\",\"contact_email\",\"contact_phone1\",\"contact_phone2\",\"company_website\",\"company_linkedin\",\"registration_type\",\"status\",\"operating_sectors\",\"incorporation_year\",\"onboarding_completed_at\",\"gdrive_folder_id\";",
  parameters: [
      "ABC Software Technologies",
      "ABC",
      "CFE",
      "test@email.com",
      "9999999999",
      "",
      "",
      "",
      1,
      3,
      [
        "ADVISORY_SERVICES",
      ],
      2009,
    ],
}


What is stacktrace of the error? And could you show the createUserBorrowerMapping method as well?

public async createUserBorrowerMapping(body, transaction: Transaction) {
return await this.userBorrowerMappingModel.create(body, { transaction });
}
I have added the stack trace error in the original post
